# Javascript clock and countdown using setInterval for second count is not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm working with javascript clock and countdown using `setInterval`.

Below is the working demo and as You can see this working good. But I wonder why the second count from clock and countdown is not correctly. Example if clock second is 40 then countdown second should be 20.

Any idea how to solve this?

```js
function addZero(x)
{
  if(x < 10)
  {
    return x = '0' + x;
  }
  else
  {
    return x;
  }
}

function clockUpdate()
{
  var date = new Date();

  var h = addZero(date.getHours());
  var m = addZero(date.getMinutes());
  var s = addZero(date.getSeconds());

  $('#clock').text(h + ':' + m + ':' + s)
}
clockUpdate();
setInterval(clockUpdate, 1000);

var upComingPrayDate = new Date("Mar 20, 2021 15:30:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function()
{
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = upComingPrayDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  $("#upComingPrayTime").html(addZero(hours) + ":"+ addZero(minutes) + ":" + addZero(seconds));

  if(distance < 0)
  {
    clearInterval(x);
    alert("Done");
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Clock
<div id="clock"></div>
<br>
Countdown
<div id="upComingPrayTime"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countdown seems to be off by 1 second.
That's because you are calculating the floor value of the remaining seconds.
This can be overcome by calculating the ceiling value.

Change this line

```
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

to

```
var seconds = Math.ceil((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```